# Is there a general rule for where in the order of a primary-key index to place the partition key?

Tags: mysql, partitioning, database-partitioning

**Assume that I properly query the partition key in every query. Is there any sensible reason to place the partition key anywhere but first in line?**

I feel like there's something I'm not understanding about how the index works. Assume MySQL and InnoDB.

I think I get that, ordinarily, you place the most selective keys first and the less selective ones later. And the partition key would ordinarily be one of the less selective ones. But if the partition key is included in every query, what difference does it make to include the partition key first? Wouldn't this help in other ways, too? E.g., I won't have to include the partition key in every index if it's up front in the primary-key index: queries using other indexes can borrow the primary key from the primary-key index consistent with the leftmost-key constraint.

And I don't know if an index itself is ever partitioned but it seems like it could be if it's a covering index. (Am I right?) If so, the partition key would have to be first, no, for the partitions to work?

E.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE  `fee` (
    `fi` INT ,
    `fo` INT ,
    PRIMARY KEY ( `fi` , `fo` ) ,
) ENGINE = INNODB
PARTITION BY RANGE ( `fi` ) (
   . . .
);
```

Or . . .

```
CREATE TABLE  `fee` (
    `fi` INT ,
    `fo` INT ,
    PRIMARY KEY ( `fo` , `fi` ) ,
) ENGINE = INNODB
PARTITION BY RANGE ( `fi` ) (
   . . .
);
```

Which, if either, is inherently better, and why or why not?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I understood none of that (presumably it's aimed at others who would understand it)

Comment: I don't know. But just to observe that the InnoDB engine always implicitly attaches the pk to the end of an index.

Comment: I revised the question. I am basically asking if it's always a good idea to declare your primary-key index by listing your partition keys first. And why or why not.

Comment: Did you also try asking in the dba forum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"you place the most selective keys first and the less selective ones later" -- No.  That is an old wives tale.

Put keys that are tested with '=' first is a simple and more important rule.

Think of a composite InnoDB BTree index as working this way.  Concatenate all the columns together, then picture the BTree as having a single string as the key.

Putting the "partition key" first in an index is the least useful place!  You are already pruning on that; having it in the index is actually redundant.  However, it is *necessary* for any Unique key (that includes the `PRIMARY KEY').

Yes, you correctly observed that the PK columns are implicitly included in every secondary key, hence the partition key is included.

Note that if the partition key is not really part of a desired `UNIQUE` key, then the uniqueness constraint is not possible (in MySQL).  However, the tacked-on PK is not part of the uniqueness constraint.  Since MySQL is only willing to check uniqueness for one partition, you must include the partition key to also provide the semantics that states "Unique" across the entire table.  (Yeah, it is a bit convoluted; live with it.)

In your example, if you do `SELECT .. WHERE fi BETWEEN 1 and 2` AND fo=3, any index (the PK is an index) *starting* with `fi` would work harder than if `fo` were *first* in the index.

So, a Rule of Thumb is to move the partition key to the *end* of any index that includes it.  (I have seen only one rare exception; I forget the details.)

Comment: "Put keys that are tested with '=' first is a simple and more important rule.

Think of a composite InnoDB BTree index as working this way. Concatenate all the columns together, then picture the BTree as having a single string as the key."

Interesting, and I'm surmising that's because "=" is quicker and putting it first enables the string to get cut down quicker, saving memory sooner. Right?

Comment: @JackAdder999 - I think it gets too complicated to quite do the "prefixing" you are suggesting.  `FLOAT`, utf8, `SIGNED` vs `UNSIGNED`, etc, imply that it really has to "compare" column by column.  The "concatenate" is a trick to get people from thinking that the BTree somehow has a tree for one column, with subtrees for the next column; this leads to drawing wrong conclusions.

Answer (score 2):

The selectivity of the two columns doesn't matter as much as some people think.

If you were to query the table as:

```
SELECT ... FROM fee WHERE fi=? AND fo=?
```

Then what does it matter if it searches the B-tree by `fi,fo` or by `fo,fi`? It'll find the same record in the end, and it'll take roughly the same number of steps to do that. There's a theoretical difference, but in most cases it won't make a significant difference.

What's more important is if you have queries that only search for one or the other column of the primary key.

You mentioned that all queries search on the partition column, that's `fi` in this example. Do you have any queries that search on `fi` but not `fo`?

```
SELECT ... FROM fee WHERE fi=?
```

If `fi` were the first column of the primary key, this would do partition-pruning, and also use the PRIMARY KEY index because your search term is on the first column.

```
mysql> explain partitions select * from fee where fi = 175;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | fee   | p2         | ref  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
```

Whereas if `fi` were the second column of the primary key, then it could do partition-pruning, but not use the index.

```
mysql> explain partitions select * from fee where fi = 175;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | fee   | p2         | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
```

Indexes are also partitioned. Think of partitioning as a series of completely separate tables, with the same columns and same indexes, just a subset of the rows. Once the query determines which partition to read, it does the query the same way it would against a non-partitioned table, choosing an index based on the query criteria. Will it use the primary key to search?

```
mysql> explain partitions select * from fee where fi = 175 and created_at < now();
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | fee   | p2         | range | created_at    | created_at | 6       | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------+
```

Here we see the condition on `fi` resulted in partition pruning, and yet the index on `created_at` was preferred by the optimizer. It searches that index in the respective partition.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is great. I think this answers my question. Basically, with respect to `SELECT ... FROM fee WHERE fi=?`, no matter where `fi` is in the primary-key index, there will be partition pruning. Keeping `fi` first so that the primary-key index may be used should therefore make a difference to the extent `fi` needs to be . . . not sure this is the right word but . . . scanned. Or searched. So if there's one value of `fi` per partition, it really makes no difference.

Comment: I think my issue was that I was conflating partitions and indexes in some ways.

Comment: Yes. Understanding any technology is aided by first understanding the technical terms.

Comment: I had already tried to upvote it but it wouldn't let me. Or, rather, it said that the vote was recorded but not displayed because I'm too new and therefore suck. Or something like that.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot -- it requires 15 reputation to upvote. Sorry, my mistake. (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

Comment: "Keeping fi first so that the primary-key index may be used should therefore make a difference to the extent fi needs to be . . . not sure this is the right word but . . . scanned. Or searched. So if there's one value of fi per partition, it really makes no difference." Is this actually true? Even if there is one value per partition for `fi`, is there still a drag on not being able to use the index?

Comment: In another words, MySQL wouldn't "know" that there's one value per partition and would still therefore want to match a value for `fi` after partition pruning. If it cannot use the index, it will have to go to the physical location of `fi` on the disk and do a match (which it won't "know" is redundant).

Comment: Let's add for flavor that we have a partition by key and sub-partition by range.

Comment: Think of a telephone book. It's like an index on `(last_name, first_name)`. You can look up someone by last name efficiently, but if you only know their first name, the order of the phone book doesn't help you, so you potentially have to scan the whole book. Therefore, the order of columns in an index is important.

Comment: You might like my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really). There's also a [video of me presenting this](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really) available.

Comment: Yes, I looked at that presentation, actually. So, even if `first_name` is the partition col and there is only one first name (it is "Norb;" everyone is named "Norb" in my world) I will have a performance problem unless I add another index of `first_name`?

Comment: Right, if there's only one value that occurs in every row in the partition, there's no point to having an index, since the search would match all the rows anyway. In fact, MySQL is smart enough to skip using the index if you search for a value that is so common that it would be more costly to use the index than to not use the index.

Comment: Good stuff. Thank you.

Comment: Consider searching with `INDEX(last_name, first_name)` for `Karwin, B.` or `K., Bill`.  Then ponder how partitioning `BY RANGE(last_name)` helps or doesn't.  Then ponder `BY RANGE(first_name)`.  (Note that an initial is done via `LIKE "K%"` and that is a "range".)